# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'translate'

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Ubuntu as OS, pymysql, flask, sqlalchemy frameworks. Then I do GET request I have this error:

```
  File "/srv/MSH/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/converters.py", line 73, in _escape_unicode
    return value.translate(_escape_table)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

My routes.py code:

```
@app.route('/device/<dev_id>/<name>/<dev_type>/<state>', methods=['GET'])
def device(dev_id, state, dev_type, name):
    # This function communicates with device
    dev_state = 0
    device = Devices.query.filter_by(dev_id=id).first()
    # Check state
    if state == "0":
        state = False
    if state == "1":
        state = True
    if device is None:
        # if we don't know device write to database
        dev = Devices(dev_id=dev_id, type=dev_type, prev_state=state, name=name)
        db.session.add(dev)
        db.session.commit()
        return "hi"
    else:
        # Write data to database and return wanted state
        device.prev_state = state
        if device.state:
            dev_state = 1
        if not device.state:
            dev_state = 0
        db.session.commit()
        return str(dev_state)
```

Comment: I think this is not a problem of your code but of pymysql`s code. You can only check if there is an update for this library available.

Comment: Can you add the full traceback? Hard to tell which of the lines is throwing the exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong line here:

```py
device = Devices.query.filter_by(dev_id=id).first()
```

You are query sql with something identical to internal python function. I think correct string is:

```py
device = Devices.query.filter_by(dev_id=dev_id).first()
```